# Updating @material-ui/core to version 4.2.0 causes react hook errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, react-hooks

I am creating an electron application using react and material-ui. I just updated material-ui to version 4.2.0. The following lines were added to my dependencies in `package.json`.

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.2.0",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
```

This was the only change I made and now my app is not working, and crashing with the following error.

> Uncaught Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call.

Strangely enough, I am not even using hooks in my react application yet. The error message persists until I remove all usage of material-ui in my application. I have also tried rebuilding my application and regenerating `yarn.lock` and `node_modules` but that did not work. I am puzzled with how simply updating material-ui to a newer stable release could cause this error. Has anyone had this problem and/or have a solution? Thank you.

**UPDATE:**
I tried reproducing the issue on codesandbox.io but it works fine there. That makes me think that something in my environment is not comparable with material-ui. I am using electron-webpack to bundle my application, and am using typescript. I see no reason why this would cause the problem but if anyone can say otherwise I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Please share your full `package.json` file

Comment: Actually, I was able to solve the problem. I'll upload an answer.

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like the problem for me was in the `package.json`. If I move

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.2.0",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
```

from `dependencies` to `devDependencies`, it works fine. I have no idea why this would cause an error about react hooks, but at least there is a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Check the full error message. You probably have multiple versions of react installed.